# Creating a watchdog to capture minidumps

Tags: c++, winapi, watchdog, minidumpwritedump

I'm trying to add the functionality of capturing mini-dumps when my program crashes. From what I've read, this is best achieved by use of another application (the watchdog) that is used to host the real application, and performs the dump.

From looking at posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590980/how-do-i-get-at-the-exception-information-when-using-minidumpwritedump-out-of-pr), I've come up with the following (both App and WatchDog are implemented in C++ using Win32):

- When the watchdog starts, it creates 2 events, an **ExitedOk** event, and an **Exception** event, both of which are set to be inheritable and aren't signalled. It also creates an inheritable file mapping.
- The watchdog then launches the "real app", and waits in a **WaitOnMultipleObjects** for either **ExitedOk** or **Exception** to be signalled.
- When the app starts, it creates the same 2 events (it will inherit the handles)
- The app is configured such that if it exits ok, it signals **ExitedOk**, or if an unhandled exception occurs, it stores the exception/thread info using the inherited filemapping, signals **Exception**, and then sleeps(Infinite).
- If the WaitOnMultipleObjects in the watchdog is signalled with an **ExitedOk**, nothing happens. If it is signalled with an **Exception**, then it reads the exception/thread info using the filemapping, and then calls MiniDumpWriteDump.

Clearly the Sleep() is an issue. Is this best resolved through another event? Such that the App waits until the watchdog signals some "FinishedCreatingDump" event?

Secondly, I thought that the whole point of the watchdog was so that you weren't doing any work in the crashed process that is potentially unstable? If I'm understanding the workflow correctly, and that you do indeed need the SetEvent/OpenFileMapping/MapViewOfFile in the process that actually crashed, isn't that just as bad as calling MiniDumpWriteDump from it?

Comment: When the SEH handler steps in you are at a safe place to execute code like [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx). Even if your stack is corrupted underneath this has no adverse effect on calling `MiniDumpWriteDump`. A corrupted stack prevents your application from continuing to run, but it has no effect on code that executes on top of it.

Comment: The remarks in MiniDumpWriteDump recommend that it shouldn't be called from the same process.

Comment: Unfortunately the recommendation doesn't come with a rationale, to understand when good advice turns bad. The loader lock scenario is possible, when delay-loading modules with a faulting `DllMain`, or invoking `LoadLibrary` explicitly or during COM server activation. The specific conditions under which this happens are not documented. Likewise, none of the other *"of many potential side effects"* are spelled out.